# com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (8548 > 1024)

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting below error intermittently while trying to insert data in mysql DB from my java code.

"PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Packet for query is too large (8548 > 1024). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (8548 > 1024). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable."

my.inf files looks like this

"# The maximum size of one packet or any generated or intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the
"# mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function.
max_allowed_packet=500M"

Once I restart the mysql server it works fine, no error. But after few days again same error.

Can anyone help me resolving this error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems at least similar to a (denied) [bug report #76816 at MySQL bug database](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76816).

The suggestion there is to make sure the `max_allowed_packet` setting is not changed from somewhere else. They offer advice in terms of how to use MySQL logging for finding out who/what changes the setting. Quote:

> [...]
>   We suspect that since max allowed packet is dynamic
>   variable and can be changed globally so some user/script(connection
>   string somewhere resetting this value) is changing it internally.
>   May be you want to enable  logging(at the MySQL and/or at app level )
>   and try to identify who/how this is changed.
>
> Please refer this page for various logging details -
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-logs.html